# Passing javascript variable to editorviewdata

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a kendo grid with EditorTemplate insie, My kendo grid will pass data to EditorTemplate using EditorViewdata.

here is my Grid

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<ClientRevenueViewModel>()
.Name("grid")
.Columns(columns =>
{
    columns.Bound(c => c.ClientId).Title("Master client")
    .EditorTemplateName("ClientTypeahead")
    .EditorViewData(new
    {
        firstFilteId = "should be firstfilter from javascript variable",  secondFilterId="should be second filter from javascript variable", combinationType=Model.FilterBy        
    });        
})
.ColumnMenu()    
.Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine))
.Resizable(resizable => resizable.Columns(true))
.Sortable()
.Pageable()
.Events(e =>
{
    e.Edit("onEdit");
    e.DataBound("onRowBound");
})
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
    .Ajax()
    .PageSize(50)
    .Read(read => read.Action("GetRevenueTarget", "RevenueTarget").Data("getParameters"))
    .Update(read => read.Action("Update", "RevenueTarget"))        
    .Model(model =>
    {
        model.Id(p => p.ClientId);            
    })
    .Events(e => e.RequestEnd("onRequestEnd"))
)
)
```

and here is my template

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()   
.Name("ClientId") 
.DataTextField("Name")
.DataValueField("Id")
.OptionLabel("Select master client")
.DataSource(source =>
{
    source.Read("GetClients", "RevenueTarget", new { firstFilteId =       ViewData["firstFilteId"], secondFilterId =  ViewData["secondFilterId"], combinationType = ViewData["combinationType"] });
 })   
.AutoBind(false)
.Events(x => x.Select("populateRow"))
   )


<script>
var firstFilter = "71";
var secondFilter = "2"; 

</script>
```

So how can I pass firstFilter and secondFilter to EditorViewData.

Comment: razor code executes at server before all your js code

Comment: @Shyju, actually I am thinking if their is something similar on Read where they can pass parameter from javascript using .Data